# Stuck on how to make activity stop playing ringtone after close

Tags: android

I'm a noob and i'm having trouble stopping the music in my app, it keeps playing long after i close the app. heres some code i hope someone can help! Here's the part i need help with, the rest of the code works.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.ContextMenu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tones extends Activity {
    int selectedSoundId;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tones);

        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        final Resources res = getResources();

        // Keep them in the same order
        final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.s1, R.id.s2,
                R.id.s3, R.id.s4, R.id.s5,
                R.id.s6, R.id.s7,
                R.id.s8, R.id.s9, R.id.s10,
                R.id.s11, R.id.s12, R.id.s13,
                R.id.14, R.id.s15 };
        final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2,
                R.raw.s3, R.raw.s4, R.raw.s5,
                R.raw.s6, R.raw.s7,
                R.raw.s8, R.raw.s9, R.raw.s10,
                R.raw.s11, R.raw.s12, R.raw.s13,
                R.raw.s14, R.raw.s15, };


    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
                // the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the
                // corresponding
                // sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
                for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                    if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                        selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res
                                .openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                        player.reset();
                        try {
                            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            player.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        player.start();

                    }

                    else if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                        selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                        player.pause();
                        finish();



                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // set the same listener for every button ID, no need
        // to keep a reference to every button
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            Button soundButton = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
            registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
            soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save As...");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle() == "Ringtone") {
            function1(item.getItemId());
        } else if (item.getTitle() == "Notification") {
            function2(item.getItemId());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void function1(int id) {

        if (savering(selectedSoundId)) {
            // Code if successful
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Code if unsuccessful
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void function2(int id) {
        if (savenot(selectedSoundId)) {
            // Code if successful
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Code if unsuccessful
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Save into Ring tone Folder

    public boolean savering(int ressound) {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(
                ressound);
        try {
            buffer = new byte[fIn.available()];
            fIn.read();
            fIn.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/media/ringtone/";

        String filename = "sounds1" + selectedSoundId + ".mp3";

        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream save;
        try {
            save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            save.write(buffer);
            save.flush();
            save.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

        File k = new File(path, filename);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, selectedSoundId);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "sounds");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                .getAbsolutePath());
        getContentResolver().delete(
                uri,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

        return true;
    }

    // Save in Notification Folder

    public boolean savenot(int ressound) {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(
                ressound);
        int size = 0;

        try {
            size = fIn.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            fIn.read(buffer);
            fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/media/notification/";

        String filename = "sounds" + selectedSoundId + ".mp3";

        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream save;
        try {
            save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            save.write(buffer);
            save.flush();
            save.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

        File k = new File(path, filename);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, selectedSoundId);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "sounds");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                .getAbsolutePath());
        getContentResolver().delete(
                uri,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);

        return true;
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onPause`, `onDestroy` of your Activity and disabling / removing the player in there?

Comment: where would I put that? I've tried putting a onDestroy at the bottom of my activity, but it didn't work. I have the updated code above if you can check it out that would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Give path of your media file

      String path="";

          MediaPlayer  Uri myUri = Uri.parse(audPath[songIndex]);   

       mp=new MediaPlayer();
           mp.setLooping(false);
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityName.this, myUri);

       mp.start();



         //stop music file on completion
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mp.stop();
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Pradeep for the musicfileId i'm confused as far as what to put, here's the top part of my code, I have a string for all of the sounds and titles.